# how to write a js script to make data import from a form error free

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have implemented a HTML webpage which has a form, now I want to add a script to it to load (import) form input given by user and do check if all of it is white spaces and if it is then give error message otherwise proceed. I want to achieve this using Javascript. I could not find the method to do so, I tried disabling the button until length of string is not equal to number of whitespaces, but that doesn't seems efficient.

Comment: share to code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 validation [See Link for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

You can add attributes like `required` to your html. This also allows you to set custom error messages if the input is not valid.
In JS, you can check `if($form.valid)`

You can use jQuery to disable the submit button until its valid also.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // by default submit button is disabled
    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

    // Enable button only if there is required text in the input field
    document.querySelector('#id1').onkeyup = () => {
    var my_string = document.querySelector('#id1').value;
    var spaceCount = (my_string.split(" ").length - 1);
    if (document.querySelector('#id1').value.length != spaceCount)
        document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    else
        document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    };  
});
```